# IntelliJ IDEA Class Files Disappear Upon Compilation

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm brand new to IntelliJ but have been working with java for years. In IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.6, when I first create a .java file and then compile it, the .class file with the same name appears in the 'out/production' folder just as its supposed to. But if I do anything to the java file to get a compile error, the class file disappears from the folder. Is this some weird setting in IntelliJ? Do I have a bad installation?

Comment: Maybe it does autobuild/autoclean?

Comment: When there is a compile error, the compiler can't create a .class file. IDEA probably deletes the .class file for the previous version before compiling.

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior, though it's only problematic with generated source files. Has any solution been found?

Answer (score 0):

This is because IntelliJ is rebuilding automatically when you change the file. To avoid having the files deleted, go to the Compiler section in the Properties (Cmd+, [Mac] Ctrl+Alt+S [Win]) and uncheck the "Clear output directory on rebuild".

Comment: This also does not work for generated source files. Any solution that prevents classes from generated source files from getting blown away (and not re-built) would be GREATLY appreciated.